# Magento 1.7 Trying to render content from a Block within the backend

Tags: magento

**Solved:**
stupid of me, I had compilation enabled... turned it off and things worked as expected. Thank you anyways for your time :)

I'm going mad. I've been trying everything (except the right one) to get this working but no content is rendered except the standard menu.
I'm trying to create a simple Block that renders a "hello" in the backend, If I for example copy the 
If i copy Mage's block from catalog.xml it works fine

```
<block type="adminhtml/catalog_product" name="products_list">
```

Please advice.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Wish_Scheduleproduct>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Wish_Scheduleproduct>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <scheduleproduct>
                <class>Wish_Scheduleproduct_Model</class>
            </scheduleproduct>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <scheduleproduct>
                <class>Wish_Scheduleproduct_Helper</class>
            </scheduleproduct>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <scheduleproduct>
                <class>Wish_Scheduleproduct_Block</class>
            </scheduleproduct>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <scheduleproduct>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Wish_Scheduleproduct</module>
                    <frontName>scheduleproduct</frontName>
                </args>
            </scheduleproduct>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <wish_scheduleproduct>
                    <file>scheduleproduct.xml</file>
                </wish_scheduleproduct>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <scheduleproduct>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Wish_Scheduleproduct</module>
                    <frontName>scheduleproduct</frontName>
                </args>
            </scheduleproduct>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <scheduleproduct>
                    <file>scheduleproduct.xml</file>
                </scheduleproduct>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <menu>
            <scheduleproduct translate="title">
                <title>Schedule product</title>
                <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                <depends>
                    <module>Wish_Scheduleproduct</module>
                </depends>
                <children>
                    <openings translate="title">
                        <title>Handle open hours</title>
                        <action>scheduleproduct/admin_schedule</action>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    </openings>
                </children>
            </scheduleproduct>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

scheduleproduct.xml (layout updates)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <scheduleproduct_admin_schedule_index>
        <reference name="menu">
            <action method="setActive"><menupath>scheduleproduct/openings</menupath></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="scheduleproduct/admin_test" name="myTester" />
        </reference>
    </scheduleproduct_admin_schedule_index>
</layout>
```

ScheduleController.php

```
class Wish_Scheduleproduct_Admin_ScheduleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

    }
}
```

The Block

```
<?php

class Wish_Scheduleproduct_Block_Admin_Test extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        echo "Hello";;      
    }
}
```

Filetree here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0QLG.png

Thank you for your help!

I've checked the include paths generated from the method mageFindClassFile and it does not seem to include the Block path.

Comment: Could it be as simple as removing the double semi-colons in your "Block" code?

Comment: Oh no my friend, that would be to easy.

Comment: is there any errors in /var/log/* files?

Comment: I agree with @Norton, check your system.log files for any indication of foul play. They are often revealing!

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your module structure and a block was successfully added to the page for me.  Download the archive [here](http://alanstorm.com/2013/projects/Wish_Scheduleproduct.tar) and diff against your own version.  The three possible culprits I see are

1. If you have another module adding a block named `myTester`, weird things may happen
2. You didn't mention where your `scheduleproduct.xml` was.  Make sure it's in the right place and being processed by Magento
3. Your block file had an `echo "hello"` in the constructor.  That will work, but it will print out the word "hello" at the top of the page.  It won't add things to the content area.  If you want things added to the content area, have a `_toHtml` return a string.  (see linked module for an example of this)

[image]

Comment: Thank you all, it seems you put me on the right track. I checked my logs and i see this error: exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: 'Wish_Scheduleproduct_Block_Admin_Test' in /var/www/gzracing/app/Mage.php:594

I've checked the filepaths and permissions, everything seems Ok but still no Hello.